# Intellij Undo last navigation operation

Tags: intellij-idea

Where can I setup shortcut for last navigation operation? I mean in my program doesn't work navigating with arrows, only with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File > Settings > Keymap > Main Menu > Navigate

I suppose you need "Back" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> by default), "Forward" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> by default).

Note that you might have software installed that clashes with these shortcuts like video card settings software (in Windows) on Windows and the window manager (in Ubuntu).

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 it's not enough to disable multiple workspaces, you have to manually go to `Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Navigation` and disable `Switch to workspace left` and `Switch to workspace right` shortcuts.